# Calling Python code from Gnome Shell extension

Tags: python, gnome-shell

I was looking for some time, but still can't find any documented way to call python functions from GnomeShell extension code. Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Simple question since you find your answer : Is there a way to get a number from that python script ? Like the exit status or such ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this :)

```
const Util = imports.misc.util;
let python_script = '/path/to/python/script';
Util.spawnCommandLine("python " + python_script);
```

Comment: Anyway to get the output from the spawned script?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to directly call a python function from Gnomeshell, but there is an alternative way. As gnomeshell is programmed with Javascript you could use a [python to javascript compiler](http://pyjs.org/) to translate the python functions you need.

Comment: Ok, I think this isn't solution I'm looking for, but it can be useful in some other project. I decided to communicate with Python script using DBus mechanism.